# ModSecurity rules - How to block most countries bar choosen few

Tags: apache, server, mod-security

At the momemnt we have a rule that blocks one country (testing purposes only).
Ideally we would like to allow only three countries (Ireland, England, Wales, Scotland) to be able to access the domain.

So we are using this:

```
# Test IP address and block by country code
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup"  "phase:1,chain,id:10,drop,log,msg:'Blocking German IP Address'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq DE"
SecRule SERVER_NAME "name of domain" // changed for privacy reasons
```

Any input will be great !

Answer (score 0):

Just change second line to this (untested):

```
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@pm IE GB" "chain"
```

However I would say that this is easily circumvented and only as reliable as the geolookup data.